# How can I skip the first two sets of results in my CSV file via PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I'm  trying to work out how to exclude the first two sets of results in my CSV file using my php. This is what I'm currently using and how it appears:
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xhhv.png)

```
<?php
$file = file('uploadfile.csv');
foreach($file as $line){
list($activityid,$activitystatus,$wbscode,$wbsname,$activityname,$keymilestones,$originalduration,$remainingduration,$plannedstart,$plannedfinish,$totalfloat,$variancebl1startdate,)=explode(",", $line);  

echo "<h1>$activityname</h1>";
echo "<b>Activity ID: </b>$activityid<hr>";
echo "<b>WBS Code: </b>$wbscode<hr>";
echo "<b>WBS Name: </b>$wbsname<hr>";
echo "<b>Activity Status: </b>$activitystatus<hr>";
echo "<b>Key Milestones: </b>$keymilestones<hr>";
echo "<b>Original Duration: </b>$originalduration<hr>";
echo "<b>Remaining Duration: </b>$remainingsuration<hr>";
echo "<b>Planned Start: </b>$plannedstart<hr>";
echo "<b>Planned Finish: </b>$plannedfinish<hr>";
echo "<b>Total Float: </b>$totalfloat<hr>";
echo "<b>Variance B11 Start Date: </b>$variancebl1startdate<hr>";


}
?>
```

Comment: use the variable which will be toogle it's state after first iteration.

Comment: foreach($file as **$n =>** $line) {**if ($n < 2) continue;** list(...)=explode(",", $line); ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag and check its incremented value to perform echo:

```
<?php
$file = file('uploadfile.csv');
$i = 0;
foreach($file as $line){
    if($i > 1) {
        list($activityid, $activitystatus, $wbscode, $wbsname, $activityname, $keymilestones, $originalduration, $remainingduration, $plannedstart, $plannedfinish, $totalfloat, $variancebl1startdate,) = explode(",", $line);

        echo "<h1>$activityname</h1>";
        echo "<b>Activity ID: </b>$activityid<hr>";
        echo "<b>WBS Code: </b>$wbscode<hr>";
        echo "<b>WBS Name: </b>$wbsname<hr>";
        echo "<b>Activity Status: </b>$activitystatus<hr>";
        echo "<b>Key Milestones: </b>$keymilestones<hr>";
        echo "<b>Original Duration: </b>$originalduration<hr>";
        echo "<b>Remaining Duration: </b>$remainingsuration<hr>";
        echo "<b>Planned Start: </b>$plannedstart<hr>";
        echo "<b>Planned Finish: </b>$plannedfinish<hr>";
        echo "<b>Total Float: </b>$totalfloat<hr>";
        echo "<b>Variance B11 Start Date: </b>$variancebl1startdate<hr>";
    }
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a for loop starting after the second element:

```
<?php
$file = file('uploadfile.csv');

for($i = 2; $i < count($file); $i++){

        list($activityid, $activitystatus, $wbscode, $wbsname, $activityname, $keymilestones, $originalduration, $remainingduration, $plannedstart, $plannedfinish, $totalfloat, $variancebl1startdate,) = explode(",", $file[$i]);

        echo "<h1>$activityname</h1>";
        echo "<b>Activity ID: </b>$activityid<hr>";
        echo "<b>WBS Code: </b>$wbscode<hr>";
        echo "<b>WBS Name: </b>$wbsname<hr>";
        echo "<b>Activity Status: </b>$activitystatus<hr>";
        echo "<b>Key Milestones: </b>$keymilestones<hr>";
        echo "<b>Original Duration: </b>$originalduration<hr>";
        echo "<b>Remaining Duration: </b>$remainingsuration<hr>";
        echo "<b>Planned Start: </b>$plannedstart<hr>";
        echo "<b>Planned Finish: </b>$plannedfinish<hr>";
        echo "<b>Total Float: </b>$totalfloat<hr>";
        echo "<b>Variance B11 Start Date: </b>$variancebl1startdate<hr>";
}
```